# How can I replace each digit with digit[space]?

Tags: php, regex, string

I have string with mix characters and numbers, how to search for numbers and replace it with the new format?

Input:

```
abc def 123 456
```

expected output:

```
abc def 1 2 3  4 5 6
```

I have tried:

```
preg_replace('/\D/', '', $c)
```

But this is not dynamic.

**EDIT:**

I forgot to add, that if the numbers have a leading `$` it shouldn't replace the numbers.

Comment: Have you tried something (research; pseudo code; code) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work for you:

So you want to replace digits, means use [`\d`](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php) (`[0-9]`) and not `\D` (which is everything else). Then you want to replace each digit with: `X` -> `X` . Put that together to:

```
$c = preg_replace("/(\d)(?!$)/", "$1 ", $c);
```

> I just realize that I need to skip any number starting with $ ($1234). what adjustment should I use in regex?

```
$c = preg_replace('~\$\d+(*SKIP)(*F)|(\d)(?!$)~', "$1 ", $c);
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/bY3yN8/1)

Comment: Thanks Rizier, this is what exactly I need in my issue in twilio. THanks for the help

Comment: @Rizier, I just realize that I need to skip any number starting with $ ($1234). what adjustment should I use in regex? tnx

Comment: @Monnster So do you mean when numbers are in parentheses, don't replace them or only if they are in that exact format: `$ ($XXXX...)` ?

Comment: if the number have dollar sign dont replace

Answer (score 1):

A primitive but functional way to do this would be:

```
<?php

$input = 'abc def 123 456';
$mapping = [
    '1' => '1 ',
    '2' => '2 ',
    '3' => '3 ',
    '4' => '4 ',
    '5' => '5 ',
    '6' => '6 ',
    '7' => '7 ',
    '8' => '8 ',
    '9' => '9 ',
    '0' => '0 ',
];
foreach ($mapping as $before => $after) {
    $input = str_replace($before, $after, $input);
}

echo $input;
```

Also, you could generate your mapping programatically if you so chose.

Comment: Absolute no need for a foreach loop. `str_replace()` also can take an array as argument.

Answer (score 1):

Use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-replace.php):

```
$str = "abc def 123 456";
$result = preg_replace('/(\d)/', ' \1 ', $str);
echo $result;
> "abc def  1  2  3   4  5  6 "
```

to remove the last space use [substr](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.substr.php):

```
echo substr($result,0,-1);
> "abc def  1  2  3   4  5  6"
```

Comment: how about if I want to skip any numbers beginning with $ ($1234).

Comment: I will be using this in twilio, twilio read all numbers as price